# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una estructura como parametro?

Tags: c++, array, estructuras

Estoy haciendo este programa con estructuras y funciones, al momento de llamar a la funcion `promedio` me da este error:

```
[Error] could not convert '(alumno*)(& x)' from 'alumno*' to 'alumno'
```

No se que pueda estar pasando ya que ya he realizado programas similares y todo funciona bien.
Este es mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

double promedio(struct alumno m);

struct direccion{
    
    char calle[50];
    int numero;
    char colonia[50];
    
    
};

struct alumno{
    
    char nombre[50];
    
     direccion direc;
    
    int calif[3];
};


int main(){
    
    int a =4;
    alumno x[a];
    
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        
        cout<<"Digita el nombre: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].nombre;
        cout<<"Digita el calle: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].direc.calle;
        cout<<"Digita el numero de casa: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].direc.numero;
        cout<<"Digita la colonia: "<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].direc.colonia;
        
        cout<<"\n";
        
        for(int g=0; g<3; g++){
            
            cout<<"Calificacion: "<<g+1<<endl;
            cin>>x[i].calif[g];
        }
        
        cout<<"\n";
        
    }
    
    system("cls");
    
    for (int c=0; c<4; c++){
        
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<x[c].nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Calle: "<<x[c].direc.calle<<endl;
        cout<<"Numero: "<<x[c].direc.numero<<endl;
        cout<<"Coloinia: "<<x[c].direc.colonia<<endl;
        cout<<"Promedio: "<<promedio(x);        
        cout<<"\n***********************************\n";
    

}

    getch();
    return 0;

}


    double promedio(struct alumno m){
    
    int suma=0;
    int prom=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        
        suma = suma + m.calif[i];
        
    }
    
    prom= suma/3;
    
    return prom;
    }
```

Para ser mas especifico el error esta aquí:

```CPP
cout<<"Promedio:"<<promedio(x);
```

Ya probé poniendo `promedio(alumno x)` pero me da otro error.
También quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de solo pasar como parámetro un campo de la estructura en especifico o es necesario pasar toda la estructura.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: En la funcion promedio puedes elminar estas 2 lineas:`prom= suma/3;
 return prom;` y intercambiarla por esto: `return (suma/3);` y haci eliminar la variable `prom`.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta aquí:

```CPP
for (int c=0; c<4; c++){
        
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<x[c].nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Calle: "<<x[c].direc.calle<<endl;
        cout<<"Numero: "<<x[c].direc.numero<<endl;
        cout<<"Coloinia: "<<x[c].direc.colonia<<endl;
        cout<<"Promedio: "<<promedio(x);        
        cout<<"\n***********************************\n";
    

}
```

Para ser mas especifico:

```CPP
cout<<"Promedio:"<<promedio(x);
```

Al hacer: `promedio(x);` como `x` es un array de la estructura alumno, lo que haces es enviar la direccion de memoria del array alumno como argumento y no declaraste tu argumento como un puntero para que apunte al ese array. Se resuelve agregando esto: `x[c]` porque ahora estamos apuntando a una posicion del array y no a su direccion de memoria:

```CPP
cout<<"Promedio:"<<promedio(x[c]);
```